# Solving a se(3) optimization problem using SciPy?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, rigid-bodies

I want to use `scipy.optimize` package to solve a rigid body optimization problem (finding optimal translation and rotation of a object).
A way to parametrize this problem is through lie group theory and the lie algebra se(3) (often called twist coordinates). This means the state vector is composed of 6 parameters (i.e. `pose = [rho_x, rho_y, rho_z, theta_0, theta_1, theta_3]`) from which the SE(3) Transformation matrix (a composition of translation vector and rotation matrix) can be obtained through the so called 'wedge' or 'hat' operator and the matrix exponentiation. (I found [this cheat-sheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/artivis/manif/devel/paper/Lie_theory_cheat_sheet.pdf) to be an excellent overview)

Now my question: Can scipy be used to optimize a 3D pose that is parametrized by the twist coordinates? I read somewhere that such problems require 'on manifold optimization' methods. So can I use scipy's `least_square()` or `minimize(method="BFGS")` for this? or do these only work for flat euclidean spaces?

Alternatively it would also help me a lot if anyone knows of any example where scipy is used to solve a 3D pose optimization problem. I have been looking for examples for the last couple of days but without much success.

This question is a implementation specific part of a more general question I posted on the robotics stackexchange [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/22650/3d-rigid-body-pose-optimization-in-flat-euclidean-space).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a good understanding of Lie Group and Lie Algebra. If you use se(3) as variables and transfer it to SE(3) through computing loss, the problem is unconstrained and easy to be optimized by Scipy. Thus, what's your main difficulty?

To transform se(3) (Lie Algebra) to SE(3) (Lie Group), you can also use the following code:

```py
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
import numpy as np

def skew(x:np.ndarray):
    return np.array([[0,-x[2],x[1]],
                     [x[2],0,-x[0]],
                     [-x[1],x[0],0]])
def computeV(rvec:np.ndarray):
    theta = np.linalg.norm(rvec)
    skew_rvec = skew(rvec)
    skew_rvec2 = skew_rvec @ skew_rvec
    V = np.eye(3) + (1 - np.cos(theta))/theta**2 * skew(rvec) + (theta - np.sin(theta))/theta**3 * skew_rvec2
    return V
    
def toVec(SE3:np.ndarray):
    """SE3 Matrix to rvec and tvec

    Args:
        SE3 (np.ndarray): 4x4 `np.ndarray`

    Returns:
        rvec, tvec: `np.ndarray`
    """
    R = Rotation.from_matrix(SE3[:3,:3])
    rvec = R.as_rotvec()
    V = computeV(rvec)
    tvec = np.linalg.inv(V) @ SE3[:3,3]
    return rvec, tvec

def toMat(rvec:np.ndarray, tvec:np.ndarray):
    """rvec and tvec to SE3 Matrix

    Args:
        rvec (`np.ndarray`): 1x3 rotation vector\n
        tvec (`np.ndarray`): 1x3 translation vector
        
    Returns:
        SE3: 4x4 `np.ndarray`
    """
    R = Rotation.from_rotvec(rvec)
    V = computeV(rvec)
    mat = np.eye(4)
    mat[:3,:3] = R.as_matrix()
    mat[:3,3] = V @ tvec
    return mat
```

to verify:

```py
    a = np.random.rand(6)
    print("se3: {}".format(a))
    SE3 = toMat(a[:3],a[3:])
    print("SE3:{}".format(SE3))
    print("rvec:{}, tvec:{}".format(*toVec(SE3)))
```